# How to generate a good seed

Tags: perl, random, random-seed

I'm looking for a method to generate a good seed for generating different series of random numbers in processes that starts at the same time. 
I would like to avoid using one of the math or crypto libraries because I'm picking random numbers very frequently and my cpu resources are very limited.

I found few example for setting seeds. I tested them using the following method:

1. short program that picks 100 random numbers out of 5000 options. So each value has 2% chance to be selected.
2. run this program 100 times, so in theory, in a truly random environment, all possible values should be picked at least once.
3. count the number of values that were not selected at all.

This is the perl code I used. In each test I opt in only one method for generating seed:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#$seed=5432;
#$seed=(time ^ $$);
#$seed=($$ ^ unpack "%L*", `ps axww | gzip -f`);
$seed=(time ^ $$ ^ unpack "%L*", `ps axww | gzip -f`);

srand ($seed);

for ($i=0 ; $i< 100; $i++) {
        printf ("%03d \n", rand (5000)+1000);
}
```

I ran the program 100 time and counted the values NOT selected using:

```
# run the program 100 times
for i in `seq 0 99`; do /tmp/rand_test.pl ; done  > /tmp/list.txt
# test 1000 values (out of 5000). It should be good-enough representation.
for i in `seq 1000 1999`; do echo -n "$i  "; grep -c $i /tmp/list.txt; done   | grep " 0" | wc -l
```

The table shows the result of the tests (Lower value is better):

```
count      Seed generation method
114    default - the line: "srand ($seed);" is commented ou
986    constant seed (5432)
122    time ^ $$
125    $$ ^ unpack "%L*", `ps axww | gzip -f`
163    time ^ $$ ^ unpack "%L*", `ps axww | gzip -f`
```

The constant seed method showed 986 or 1000 values not selected. In other words, only 1.4% of the possible values were selected. This is close enough to the 2% that was expected.

However, I expected that the last option that was recommended in few places, would be significantly better than the default.

Is there any better method to generate a seed for each of the processes?

Comment: Do you need repeatable "randomness" in your application?  How will the random numbers you will generate be used?

Comment: No. To get repeatable "randomness" I can simply use the same seed.

Comment: Can you answer my other question: How will the random numbers you generate be used?  If the numbers will further information security in any way (e.g., they serve as random passwords, nonces, or encryption keys), then you should simply use a cryptographic RNG (such as `Crypt::URandom` in Perl) and generate _random numbers_ with it rather than _seeds_.

Comment: Using the random number I'll compose a "user name": `$user_name_to_fetch = sprintf("name%015d", rand($max_user_id));`  to query from a database. 
I'd like to cover most database in a minimal time by running queries in multiple client processes.

How can I use `Crypt::URandom` to generate a random number? It generates random strings.

Comment: Crypt::Random::Seed. Try it, and benchmark / profile its performance using the TESHA2-strong method. It's probably plenty fast if you only call it when you need a seed. Once you've seeded a RNG, you shouldn't have to seed it again for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm picking random numbers very frequently and my cpu resources are very limited.

You're worrying before you even have made a measurement.

> Is there any better method to generate a seed for each of the processes?

[Yes.](https://sockpuppet.org/blog/2014/02/25/safely-generate-random-numbers/) You have to leave user space which is prone to manipulation. Simply use [Crypt::URandom](http://p3rl.org/Crypt::URandom).

- It is safe for any purpose, including fetching a seed.
- It will use the kernel CSPRNG for each operating system ([see source code](https://metacpan.org/release/Crypt-URandom/source/lib/Crypt/URandom.pm)) and hence avoid the problems shown in the article above.
- It does not suffer from the [documented `rand` weakness](https://www.nu42.com/2010/09/be-vary-of-using-built-in-rng-for.html).

Comment: tnx. very interesting reference. 
When I tested the code in [documented rand weakness](https://www.nu42.com/2010/09/be-vary-of-using-built-in-rng-for.html) It returned 1000000. 
When I changes the mapping to:
`my %r = map { int(rand(1_000_000)) => undef } 1 .. 1_000_000;`

it started returning values around 632K.

Comment: I looked at [Crypt::URandom](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::URandom). How do I convert a N bytes long sting to an integer number in the range of 00 .. X  ?

Comment: Treat the bytes as a base 256 natural number with N digits. Divide by 256**N (max val) to get a rational between 0..1. Multiply by X to get a rational between 0..X. `use bignum qw(hex); use Crypt::URandom qw(urandom); my $N = 10; my $X = 10_000; my $bigint = hex unpack 'H*', urandom $N; my $smallrat = $bigint / 256**$N; print $smallrat * $X;`

Comment: @Yuval the "rand weakness" only applies to microsoft windows (actually, not true, but the weakness is considerably less for other built in rand implementations)

Answer (score 4):

Don't generate a seed. Let Perl do it for you. Don't call `srand` (or call it without a parameter if you do).

Quote [`srand`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/srand.html),

> If srand is not called explicitly, it is called implicitly without a parameter at the first use of the rand operator

and

> When called with a parameter, srand uses that for the seed; otherwise it (semi-)randomly chooses a seed.

It doesn't simply use the time as the seed.

```
$ perl -M5.014 -E'say for srand, srand'
2665271449
1007037147
```

Answer (score 1):

Your goal seems to be how to generate *random numbers* rather than how to generate *seeds*.  In most cases, just use a cryptographic RNG (such as `Crypt::URandom` in Perl) to generate the random numbers you want, rather than generate seeds for another RNG.  (In general, cryptographic RNGs take care of seeding and other issues for you.) You should not use a weaker RNG unless—

- the random values you generate aren't involved in information security (e.g., the random values are neither passwords nor nonces nor encryption keys), and
- either—

  - you care about repeatable "randomness" (which is not the case here), or
  - you have measured the performance of your application and find random number generation to be a performance bottleneck.

Since you will generate random names for the purpose of querying a database, which may be in a remote location, it will be highly unlikely that the random number generation itself will be the performance bottleneck.